# asp.net error with <form id="form1" runat="server">

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i'm a newbie programmer
i want to get rid of the traditional alert popup of javascript
i found a pop up with a good gui but it doesn't work as expected in asp.net

my problem is if i remove the

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

code it works perfectly

but if i added it in asp.net with

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

the pop up doesn't work. after clicking the button it reloads the whole site instead of pop up the message. why?
this is the whole code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            /**
             * See how to limit only one dialog can be opened at a time.
             */
            $(function () {
                var $btn = $('#btn-open');
                $btn.on('click', function (event) {
                    BootstrapDialog.closeAll();
                    var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
                        message: 'The only one.'
                    });
                    dialog.open();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

```css
        <style type="text/css">
            .floating-menu {
                background-color: gray;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                padding: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                right: 10px;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
        </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <title>Only one dialog</title>
        

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="floating-menu">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-open">Open dialog</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `button` control by default is `submit` type and it will post the form to the server, to avoid this either you can specify it as button like this:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-open">Open dialog</button>
```

Or else you can use jQuery `preventDefault` method:-

```
 $(function () {
     var $btn = $('#btn-open');
     $btn.on('click', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         BootstrapDialog.closeAll();
         var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
              message: 'The only one.'
         });
         dialog.open();
         });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir it worked. i may need to read some javascript stuff. thank you again

Comment: @knowmeifyou.. Do **upvote** and **accept the answer** if you found it useful, which I hope you did..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i did upvote the answer but i forgot to accept it sorry